# transimpedance amplifier configuration in a polygraph circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, transimpedance

I am working through an assignment to design a polygraph circuit which works off skin resistance and in the brief, it specifies that a transimpedance amplifier must be used. I have never used one of these devices and have got my circuit to work. but I have connected it in a non-inverting configuration with the feedback that looks like a Schmitt trigger.

My circuit works and I have shown a lab technician from my university, but he also has not worked with transimpedance amplifier, however he told me he does not see why it would be allowed especially since it is working. I do not know if I can connect a transimpedance amplifier in a noninverting configuration. I have not really seen much online about this topic nor in the device’s datasheet. Some of my classmates do not believe this would be allowed. Can anyone advise me if what I have done is allowed or not?

Many thanks.

[image: where the positive pin is the input]

Comment: A transimpedance amplifier converts current to voltage. It can't measure skin resistance directly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier

Comment: *but I have connected it in a non-inverting configuration with the feedback that looks like a Schmitt trigger* - that's not what your postage size schematic implies. Additionally, you can't have a non-inverting TIA unless you add a second inverting stage to the output.